# How to execute LDAP ADLDS command using cmd.exe?

Tags: cmd, ldap, adsi, adlds

We have to execute dsacls command from cmd.exe to make changes in ADLDS user's permissions. When I tried to execute through CMD I got the below error

```
dsacls \\servername.com:6395\OU=users,DC=comp,DC=com /A /I:T /G CN=UserOne,OU=users,DC=comp,DC=com:GR

The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.
The command failed to complete successfully.
```

Do I have to execute any commands before I execute dsacls command?
I'm currently using ADSI edit to do basic operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it just works.  I tested your command (locally) on a test instance I found on an old server:

```
dsacls \\localhost:60001\OU=Root,DC=TimTest /A /I:T /G CN=TestUser,CN=ADLDSUsers,DC=TimTest:GR
```

With `/A`, I had to be running 'As Administrator'; without `/A`, it wasn't necessary.

I then tested the same command from another machine, replacing localhost with the (NetBIOS) server name.  Both versions of the command (with and without `/A`) worked.

Then, whilst testing the FQDN of the server I typo'd it, and got the same error as you.

Try the most basic version of the command, a read:

```
dsacls \\servername.com:6395\OU=users,DC=comp,DC=com
```